# How to pass variables into VBScript with array

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to pass folder location as variable to a VBScript which has array to consume the location as a parameter. I don't know how to pass it, could some one please help me?

I am trying to pass following location as a variable "C:\New","C:\New1" to the below code, the script is working fine when I directly give the location, but when I tired to pass it as variable it is not working.

Code given below:

```
Set oParameters = WScript.Arguments
folderlocation = oParameters(0)
Dim folderarray
Dim WshShell, oExec
Dim wow()
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim oAPI, oBag
Dim fso, folder, file
Dim searchFileName, renameFileTo, day
Dim i
folderarray = Array(folderlocation)
ii = 0
day = WeekDay(Now())
If day = 3 Then
    aa = UBound(folderarray)
    f = 0
    j = 0
    x = 0
    Y = 0
    For i = 0 To aa
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set folder = fso.GetFolder(folderarray(i))
        For Each file In folder.Files
            If InStr(file.Name, name) = 1 Then
            ii = 1
            strid = file.Name
            Set re = New RegExp
            re.Pattern = ".*myfile.*"
            If re.Test( strid ) Then
                'msgbox "File exist and the file name is """ & strid & """"
                x = x+1
            Else
                'msgbox "file not found"
            End If
            Set re = Nothing
          End If
        Next
        If x = 0 Then
            ReDim Preserve wow(f)
            wow(f) = folderarray(i)
            f = f+1
            j = j+1
        Else
            x = 0
        End If
    Next
End If

If J > 0 Then
    ReDim Preserve wow(f-1)
    value = Join(wow, ",")
    MsgBox "Files not found in the following location(s) :" & value
Else
    MsgBox "fine"
End If
```

Comment: Explain in more detail how it isn't working and what you are expecting.   Its not working doesn't give a whole lot to go on. - I am guessing that you need to do a split on the comma to create the array,  
folderarray = Split(oParameters(0), ",")

Comment: Script does not take the variable passed from outside Example: tesxt.vbs "C:\New","C:\New1" is not working.

Comment: Let me make it simple, 
dim a
Set oParameters = WScript.Arguments
value= oParameters(0)
'a=Array(5,10,15,20)
a=Array(value)
msgbox a(3)

I tried to execute above script with variable parameter "test.vbs 5,10,15,20
it gave me an error "Subscript out of range"

Comment: use the split function as I already suggested and this will remedy the problem.   You seem to be insistent on using the Array function.  : folderarray = Split(folderlocation, ",")

Comment: My intention is to check for a file on 2 different locations (this may vary depending up on a server) Hence I planned to grab the location in to an array and check it one by one. In order to reuse the script for different machine I am trying to pass the folder location as variable. I am not sure how split will help me here!

Comment: did you even try it?!?!....  The Split function will return an array.

Comment: Thanks @Sorceri, I missed to comment on the array command which gave the error. Now it is working as expected. Many thanks for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fill an array from a list of arguments you'd call the script like this:

```
your.vbs "C:\New" "C:\New1"
```

and fill the array in `your.vbs` like this:

```
size = WScript.Arguments.Unnamed.Count - 1
ReDim folderarray(size)
For i = 0 To size
  folderarray(i) = WScript.Arguments.Unnamed.Item(i)
Next
```

---

If for some reason you must pass the folder list as a single argument you'd call the script like this:

```
your.vbs "C:\New,C:\New1"
```

and populate the array in `your.vbs` like this:

```
folderarray = Split(WScript.Arguments.Unnamed.Item(0), ",")
```